# Shell script to auto execute after checkout

Tags: git, shell

I am not even sure if this is possible but after doing some research on git I couldn't really figure out away to do this, so I thought why not stackoverflow?

Let say I have shell script or to make it more concrete, I have following commands that I want to execute once a user does the checkout from git:

```
"MachineName":~/MyStuff/SpecificFolder# find myfolder -type f
-print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
```

My goal is to have it as a shell script so it will execute after the checkout. I know git maintain file permission but I ended up seeing some strange behavior when you switch the branches. So I thought to create a shell script that way file permission always stays the same.

Comment: With "after checkout" you mean after `git checkout <some_branch>`?

Comment: @fedorqui yes after gut checkout

Answer (score 3):

Git comes with support for [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

You could add a post-commit hook script that does what you want it to do.

add your script as `post-checkout` to .git/hooks.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a function for `git ckeckout` that performs the other action after it?

```
git_checkout ()
{
    git checkout $1
    find myfolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
}
```

If you store it in your `~/.bashrc`, then whenever you want to checkout you can do `git_checkout <new_branch>` and both actions will be performed.